# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Tags: python, parameter-passing

**model.py**

```
import os

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import backbones
import decoders

class BasicModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, args):
    nn.Module.__init__(self)

    self.backbone = getattr(backbones, args['backbone'])(**args.get('backbone_args', {}))
    self.decoder = getattr(decoders, args['decoder'])(**args.get('decoder_args', {}))

def forward(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.decoder(self.backbone(data), *args, **kwargs)
```

Just in case,

In backbones, there are 'mobilenetv3.py', 'resnet.py'.

In decoders, there are 'balance_cross_entropy_loss.py', 'dice_loss.py', 'l1_loss.py', 'pss_loss.py', 'seg_detector_loss.py', 'seg_detector.py', 'simple_detection.py'

**cvs.py**

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from model import BasicModel

bm = BasicModel()
...
...
```

I'm trying to do to other task, but I have to instantiate the model first.
But I have this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cvs.py", line 7, in <module>
bm = BasicModel()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

What argument should I pass to BasicModel()?

Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: Maybe you should check the documentation for `nn.Module`?

Comment: If `args` is optional, you need to give it a default value. Otherwise, you need to pass an argument to `BasicModel` when you call it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `def __init__(self, *args):`?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared to pass the `args` in the init method:

```
def __init__(self, args):
```

So, then you're trying to instantiate the `BaseModel` object, you need to pass the `args` to the constructor.

```
bm = BasicModel(args)
```

where `args = #your defined arguments`

Comment: oh it says 'NameError: name 'args' is not defined'..

Comment: because you haven't defined args. you've defined your constructor to pass args and parse that to do something. So don't you know how to declare it? Please declare that args variable first according to your requirement.